# Computer management, Access denied only on win XP VMs

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-access, windows-xp, windows-event-log

This may take a few lines to setup, so bear with me.  My company runs vmware, mix of win xp and win 7 VMs.  My tech group have admin rights throughout the domain.  We're having some scanning issues and I am trying to get into the logs of our Win XP workstations when they lock up, however, I cannot access the event viewer through computer management.

Here is the breakdown. 
When I try to access event viewer from a Win 7 VM, I get: Access Denied (5) error. 
When I try to access event viewer from a Win xp VM, I get: Network path not found.

The odd thing is, if I try to access the logs of a win 7 vm, it works without issue.

I have tried to pull the logs from the vm by backdooring, \vm#\c\windows\system32\config.  However when I try to open them, I get Error: The Data is invalid.

I do not have access to group policy, but I am being told it is open for my tech group.  Any idea what I could look into to see what is blocking this on the xp desktops?

Thanks.